# Android, alternating row layout in a ListView, can it be done with ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I am aware that you can extend BaseAdapter and override the `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(postion)` methods and  get various row layouts that way.

However, I have just done a tutorial in which ArrayAdapter was extended and `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` was the only method overriden.

It seems to me a lot simpler just to follow this approach and use the position maybe with an if/switch to determine the view inflated for a given row.

Is that a correct assumption or are there problems with this approach?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no your assumption is wrong. if you need to `inflate` different `View`s the correct way is to `override` `getViewTypeCount()/ getItemViewType(postion)` pairs. In this way android will give you a different `convertView` to inflate based on what the `getViewTypeCount()` returns.

as stand in the docs:

`getViewTypeCount() Returns the number of types of Views that will be created`